# Protractor promises not working

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, cucumber, chai

I am implementing e2e tests with protractor and cucumber for my angular5 app. The problem is that the test below succeeds and I have no idea why.
Can somebody tell me what I'm missing here? (Might there be a problem with the promises returned by browser.getTitle and the fact that I use .js files to specify the steps?). It does not work either if I use 
`element(..).getTitle().then(..)`

```
    const {element, by} = require('protractor');
    const {Given, When, Then} = require('cucumber')
    const chai = require('chai');
    chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));

    Given('I am logged out', function (callback) {
      //nothing todo here
      callback();
    });

    When('I load the login page', function (callback) {
      browser.get('http://localhost:49999/login')
        .then(callback);
    });

    Then('I should see the title myTitle', function (callback) {
      chai.expect(browser.getTitle()).to.eventually.equal('foobar');
      chai.expect(browser.getTitle()).to.eventually.equal('myTitle');
      callback();
    });
```

Comment: Did you miss this line `chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'))` in your script?

Comment: no - I have now added the import statements in my post

Comment: Have you tried removing the `eventually`? Because `.to.eventually.equal()`  listens like it's always true. It's just a guess, I don't know `chai` that well though.